# NSPredicate on an NSArray to search for any object

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nspredicate

I have an array of objects with names, addresses, tel. nos, etc.

I want to be able to search the array for any occurrence of a term - whether in the name field, the address field, etc.

I have something like this in mind :

```
-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array


    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",searchText];
    searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[contactArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}
```

This causes an exception "Can't use in/contains operator with collection".

UPDATE. I can now search on up to three fields. When I add a fourth (in any sequence), I get this exception: "Unable to parse the format string ..."

The Predicate code is now:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.narrative contains[c] %@ OR SELF.category contains[c] %@ OR SELF.date contains[c] OR SELF.name contains[c] %@", searchText, searchText, searchText, searchText];

     searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[allDreams filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Is three a limit of predicate search fields? How do I get around this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use a predicate string that checks for them all:

```
@"name contains[cd] %@ OR address contains[cd] %@"
```

you can add as many as you want.

The only downside is that you'll need to add the same search string for each field you want to  test, which can seem a bit ugly.

If your objects are dictionaries, then there is a way to truly search all values without necessarily knowing their names at compile time, using a subquery.

It works like this:

```
@"subquery(self.@allValues, $av, $av contains %@).@count > 0"
```

It uses the `@allValues` special key (or method call if you prefer) for dictionary objects and uses that to filter any value that contains your search string. If any is found (i.e., the count is positive), the object is included in the results.

Notice that this will examine all values indiscriminately, even those that you don't want to include if you have any in your dictionary.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte notice that they are two very different answers - Kjuly's proposes two ways to check one field while mine proposes one way to check several fields. So don't just try them, but make sure you understand what you need and what the right solution is.

Comment: In addition you can use `NSCompoundPredicate` to dynamically create simple predicates and join them using `+orPredicateWithSubpredicates:`.

Comment: @all, Monolo's answer comes close to what I want, but I realize that this is more complex than I asked in my question. I have to figure how to include special chars (e.g. spaces), and items from more than one array - including many to many relations. I thought this would be an easy morning...

Comment: @Monolo - I like this approach, however, if I add more than three fields to check, I get an exception - I modified my question.. Any ideas?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte My guess is that the exception's description tells you. But at any rate, there is a syntax error in your string: there is a `%@` missing for the `SELF.date` field. So the problem is not the number of fields added.

Comment: gah, just found that.. Thanks a ton. all is well.

Comment: Hi Monolo, thanks for your answer. Is there a way to search case-INsensitive for the dictionary method? Thanks in advanced!

Comment: @Ryan Just apply the [CD] modifier to the predicate string: "... contains[cd] ..."

Answer (score 4):

I think your array item is not pure string, right?

Suppose your array item contains `name` attribute (even it's a dictionary), you can search it in this way:

```
NSPredicate * predicate =
  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@ OR name LIKE[cd] %@", searchText, searchText];
```

here, `name` can be `SELF.name`.

---

[HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795)'s an official document.

Comment: Kjuly, in this array, every object is a string object.. I've tried with SELF.name CONTAINS[c], but that just looks at the first field. I'll try with [cd]. Thanks for the link too.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte how come a string object contains name, address? do you mean like this: `name:<name>,address:<address>`? why not format it like `@{name: <name>, address: <address>}`? ;)